# Java BST recursion

Tags: java, recursion, binary-search-tree

I have recently moved from C++ to Java and now I am playing with data structures which in C++ needed usage of pointers.

I am creating BST in Java now and I used recursion for `inserting` into Tree and it is not working as I would expect. This code stores only a `Node` with `val = 5`. Can you give me any advice?

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main( String [] args )
    {
      BST<Integer> bst = new BST<Integer>();
      bst . add( 5 );
      bst . add( 10 );
    }
}

public class BST<T extends Number & Comparable<T>>
{
    private Node root;

    private class Node
    {
      private T val;
      private Node left;
      private Node right;

      Node(T val)
      {
        this . val = val;
        left = null;
        right = null;
      }
    }


    public BST()
    {
      root = null;
    }

    public BST( T val )
    {
      root = new Node( val );
    }

    public void add( T val )
    {
      if( root == null )
        root = new Node(val);
      else
        add( root, val );
    }

    private void add( Node parent, T val )
    {
      if( parent == null )
        parent = new Node(val);
      else if( val . compareTo( parent . val ) < 0 )
        add( parent . left, val );
      else if( val . compareTo( parent . val ) > 0 )
        add( parent . right, val );
    }
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java is pass-by-reference so doing `parent = new Node(val)` achieves nothing. You are merely changing the local parameter.

You need to do something like `if ( left == null ) left = new Node(val) else add (left,val)`.

Not posting code because this is likely to be a homework question.

Comment: Oukey, I have done what you said and it is working now, thank you. But if Java is pass-by-reference should not be `parent = new Node( val )` working? Before on the address of `parent` was value `null` so now on the address of `parent` should be `new Node( val )`.

Comment: @scarface - Your reference to `parent` is the **local** variable. Changing it makes no change to your structure.

Comment: @scarface When you call `add(root,val)` whatever happens to be the value of `root` is passes as a parameter (called `parent` in your case). You then do `parent = new Node(val)` which just canges that local parameter in the method. Since you never reference that parameter again the assignment does nothing.

Comment: So `parent` is not a reference on `parent . left` or `parent . right` from the previous call? This confuses me. I thought that when I pass `parent . left` or `parent . right` then `parent` should be reference on it.

Comment: @scarface In Java **everything** is a pointer to an object (well almost everything). So passing `object.left` will not refer to `object` any more. `object.left` is like `object->left`, not `&object.left`.

Comment: Still there is a confusion. That's sure that passing `object . left` will not refer to `object` any more. but `object . left` should refer to `object . left` and when I assign `object . left` a `new Node( val )` then it should stay there. I need to get to the point here because it will confuse me forever.